Device Power On Reset Requirements in SoC
I need to release the RESETn signal after  all power supplies and clocks are stable, and de-assertion should be at least 100 ms (I'm using 47nF in CT to create delay of ~200ms). My idea is to connect all PGOOD of power supplies.
And I connect it in this way (TPS3808 is Reset Supervisor):

I see in datasheet that MRn has pullup with 90k so I think that I don’t need any pullup in addition.

Will this design meet my requirements?
Edit: all PGOOD Signals open drain and there are not pull up on them.

What are the drivers for the PG_1V5, PG_P5V0, PG_P1V8 and PG_P1V2 signals, i.e. they open-drain?

@ChesterGillon YES, they all open drain

With the drivers for PG_1V5, PG_P5V0, PG_P1V8 and PG_P1V2 being open-drain, in general it should be OK to wire-and (join) them together and connect to the single /MR input on the TPS3808G01, making use of the internal 90-kΩ pull-up resistor.
The question doesn't specify which devices are being used to drive the power-good signals. One thing to check is the maximum pull-up voltage can withstand on their open drain power good pins. Taking the example of a TPS62177 with an Output Voltage Range 1 VDC to 6 V, the datasheet says:

The PG pin is an open-drain output that requires a pullup resistor (to any voltage less than 7 V).

So, the TPS62177 can handle it's PG pin being pull-up to the 3.3 V VDD of the TPS3808G01, but the datasheets of the actual devices should be checked.
